# Unable to load WSDL file error in flex while making a call to a web service

Tags: web-services, flex3, wsdl

I am trying to call a webservice from my Flex application and this is the code:

```
 <mx:WebService id="myWebService"
     wsdl="http://172.16.111.103:22222/cics/services/PRESENT1?wsdl">

     <mx:operation name="PRESENT1Operation"
          result="resultHandler(event)"
          fault="faultHandler(event)">
    </mx:operation>
 </mx:WebService>
```

//Function to send customer id to the wsdl request

```
 private function searchDetails():void{
            myWebService.PRESENT1Operation.send(cusNo.text);
            cusDetails.visible=true;
        }
```

The webservice is up and running. I have a separate Java application to test the webservice, And I am able to execute it properly. I am able to request the webservice and get response.

But If I try to call the webservice through the Flex application, I get the following error.

```
 [RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (http://172.16.111.103:22222/cics/services/PRESENT1?WSDL)"]
at mx.rpc.wsdl::WSDLLoader/faultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\wsdl\WSDLLoader.as:98]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:170]
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:225]
at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:53]
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:103]
at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/errorHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:362]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/redirectEvent()
```

Please some one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The application is unable to load as the application starts before the other modules can be loaded

I hope this might be useful
var wsdlFile :String = <>
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(wsdlFile);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);

You can get the complete path by typing in the URL append it with ?wsdl